# Mutiple http base address for self hosted WCF service?

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-endpoint

I have a WCF service that has one http endpoint,
I would like to add another http endpoint address with a different binding.
The service is not hosted in IIS and hence setting the multipleSiteBindingsEnabled
is of no use.

Am trying something like this.

```
<system.serviceModel>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />

    <services>
            <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviorConfiguration"
             name="ServerService">
                <endpoint address="http://localhost:6732/ServerService" binding="webHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="webby"
         contract="IClientAppContract">
                    <identity>
                        <dns value="localhost" />
                    </identity>
                </endpoint>
                <endpoint address="http://localhost:800/ServerService" binding="basicHttpBinding"
         contract="IClientAppContract">
                    <identity>
                        <dns value="localhost" />
                    </identity>
                </endpoint>
                <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
                <host>
                    <baseAddresses>
                        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:800/ServerService" />
                        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:6732/ServerService" />
                    </baseAddresses>
                </host>
            </service>
        </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like the config shown below. It exposes multiple endpoints through a *single* port but I'm sure this pattern of configuration is supported by WCF.

```
    <services>
        <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviorConfiguration"
                 name="ServerService">
            <endpoint address=""
                      binding="webHttpBinding"
                      behaviorConfiguration="webby"
                      contract="IClientAppContract">
                <identity>
                    <dns value="localhost" />
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
            <endpoint address="basic"
                      binding="basicHttpBinding"
                      contract="IClientAppContract">
                <identity>
                    <dns value="localhost" />
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
            <endpoint address="mex"
                      binding="mexHttpBinding"
                      contract="IMetadataExchange" />
            <host>
                <baseAddresses>
                    <add baseAddress="http://localhost:800/ServerService" />
                </baseAddresses>
            </host>
        </service>
    </services>
```

Comment: Yea, this should work, but is there any way I can have two different base addressess.

Comment: WCF uses HTTP (and any other transport) is a way that different endpoints are just different paths (routes) from a single root address. You can have different base addresses if you have different transports (i.e. net.tcp, net.msmq) but within a single transport, you can only have a single base address. I don't believe WCF offers a way in the endpoint configuration to use a specific base address for a given transport. This would be required to do what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

You could create two services that each have their own different baseAddress, but their internal endpoints are identical.